# Facebook Login API: How to unconditionally request an email?

Tags: facebook-login

[Facebook Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web) allows websites to request a specific set of information from Facebook users (referred to as "scopes"). There is a mandatory scope (*public_profile*), but we are allowed to request optional ones (such as *email*) which the user can reject.

My question is, how do I make the optional scopes mandatory? I do not want users to sign up without their email. They are free to reject the entire request, but I do not want them to sign up without all the necessary scopes. All or nothing.

I have seen sites do this:

[image]

There is no option to revoke specific scopes. How do they do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I'm guessing the key is using the API v1.0, as the permission selecting was introduced in v2.0. This is most likely what the Guardian does. Whether it's intentional or not, I don't know. By April 30th, 2015 all apps will be required to use the v2.0

A possible workaround:

I don't think there's a specific callback of the Facebook login where the status is returned. You can however use `/{user-id}/permissions` and loop through the result after the login has been initiated. If any status is not flagged as `granted`, deny the user access. As you didn't specify a language, I will write an example in PHP:

```
    $res = $facebook->api('/v2.0/me/permissions', array('fields' => 'status'));
    $granted = true;

    for($i=0;$i<count($res['data']);$i++)
    {
        echo $res['data'][$i]['status'];
        if($res['data'][$i]['status']!="granted")
        {
            $granted = false;   
        }
    }

    if($granted == true)
    {
        //Login
    }else{
        //Deny access
    }
```

Did not yet try this with an app I declined specific permissions with. But any flag other than granted should change the process.

Comment: PHP is fine, and this would indeed work, but there has to be another way. The Guardian does it for example. See: https://i.imgur.com/DC6D0Cz.png

Comment: As for that, I'm guessing the key is using the API v1.0, as the permission selecting was introduced in v2.0. This is most likely what the Guardian does. Whether it's intentional or not, I don't know.

EDIT: By April 30th, 2015 all apps will be required to use the v2.0.

Comment: Ah I see. That clears it up then. Could you please add this explanation to the top of your answer. Thanks.